# Jackson XML tag and attribute with the same name

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson

I want to get the following XML:

```
<User id="two">
    <id>one</id>
</User>
```

And I try to use Jackson XML mapper for this:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement
public class User {
    private String id;

    private String attributeId;

    public User(final String id, final String attributeId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.attributeId = attributeId;
    }

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id", isAttribute = true)
    public String getAttributeId() {
        return attributeId;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        final File file = new File("user.xml");
        final User user = new User("one", "two");

        xmlMapper.writeValue(file, user);
    }
}
```

But all I get is this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "id": com.sbconverter.parser.slovoed.User#getId(0 params) vs com.sbconverter.parser.slovoed.User#getAttributeId(0 params)
```

Can I have same name of the attribute and tag, on one object?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem, so you'll need to do extra classes for this case.

Adding a space in front of id at localName (localName = " id") can do the trick, but it's more recommended to make a new bean.